# Converting gulpfile.js to v4

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have upgraded Gulp to version 4 and I am receiving errors when doing gulp build because my gulpfile.js is outdated. I need help changing the syntax on my gulpfile.js from Gulp v3 to Gulp v4.  Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var gulpIf = require('gulp-if');
var gutil = require("gulp-util");
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var del = require('del');
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var webpackStream = require("webpack-stream");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config.js");
var injectVersion = require('gulp-inject-version');


gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('src/scss/log.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'))
});

gulp.task('images', function(){
  return gulp.src('src/images/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
});

gulp.task('webpack', function(){
  return gulp.src('src/main.js')
    .pipe(webpackStream( webpackConfig ))
    .pipe(injectVersion())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js/'));
});

gulp.task('useref', function(){
  return gulp.src('src/*.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});

gulp.task('move:js', function(){
  return gulp.src([
      'src/js/config.js.example',
      'src/js/worker.online.js',
      'src/js/worker.queue.js'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
});

gulp.task('clean:dist', function() {
  return del.sync('dist');
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'webpack'], function(){
  gulp.watch('src/scss/*', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('src/components/**/*.vue', ['webpack']);
  gulp.watch('src/*.js', ['webpack']);
});

gulp.task('build', function (callback) {
  runSequence('clean:dist',
    ['webpack', 'sass', 'images'],
    'useref',
    'move:js',
    callback
  )
});

gulp.task('default', ['webpack-dev-server', 'watch']);
```

............................................................

Comment: Did you try to rewrite it? What help do you need, exactly?

Comment: There are a couple of good articles on this: search for "how to migrate from gulp v3 to v4".

Comment: What I tried doing is putting "gulp.series" before every function, for example ```gulp.task('sass', gulp.series(function(){
  return gulp.src('src/scss/log.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'))
}));```                                                                                         
               But it hasn't worked

Comment: I am receiving the error ```AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified at Gulp.set [as _setTask]```                 Is it possible to help me rewrite my gulpfile.js?

Answer (score 1):

In vertion 4, The way you define dependent task has been changed. Here is the smaple.

```
// V3
gulp.task('default', ['del'], function() {
   // default task code here
});

// v4
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('del', function() { 
    // default task code here
}));

//v3
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles'], function() {...});

// v4 

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('scripts', 'styles'));
```

More info:

https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/how-do-i-update-to-gulp-4/

https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/

Comment: So instead of ```gulp.task('sass', function(){``` it should be ```gulp.task(gulp.series('sass', function(){```?

Comment: No, That is for multi task command like 'default', ['scripts', 'styles']. Go one by one remove the dependent task. run only induvidual task, comment out other. Once all fix and go for the combination of task

Comment: I am sorry, but can you show me how I could do the first one to get the idea. Thank you for your help